# "openpyxl.utils.exceptions.IllegalCharacterError" while writing textfile to excel

Tags: python, openpyxl

I am trying to write contents saved in **data** variable to **excel file**.

```
wb = load_workbook('results.xlsx')
wb.create_sheet('Output')
ws = wb['Output']
ws.append([str(data)])
wb.close()
```

However, I am getting this error, which says: `"openpyxl.utils.exceptions.IllegalCharacterError".`

I tried this action with **xlsxwriter** as below:

```
workbook = xlsxwriter.Workbook('results.xlsx')
worksheet = workbook.add_worksheet()    
worksheet.write(data)
```

However, I get the following error: 
`"AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'group'".`

Comment: The exception is clear: the data contains characters which may **not** be stored in Excel workbook.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to solve it with below code.

```
from openpyxl.cell.cell import ILLEGAL_CHARACTERS_RE
wb = load_workbook('results.xlsx')
wb.create_sheet('Converted_Output')
ws = wb['Converted_Output']
for x in range(7729):
    ws.cell(row = 1, column = 1).value = ILLEGAL_CHARACTERS_RE.sub(r'',str(data))
wb.save('results.xlsx')
wb.close()
```

Answer (score -2):

try  `ws.append(str(data))`
instead of
ws.append([str(data)])
maybe it will work

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion but now I'm getting error: TypeError: Value must be a list, tuple, range or generator, or a dict. Supplied value is <class 'str'>

Comment: Guesses are not answers.